# Move emails to SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, email, exchange-server

I'm looking to write an application, in .net that will scan a mailbox and put new items into a SQL Server database.

Just wondering what the best way to achieve this would be, in terms of an API. Is there an exchange specific one or a 3rd party one I could use.

It's important for me to be able to save the To/From/CC, Title, Email Body & other metadata in separate fields.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `ExchangeService` in .net. You can connect to a Exchange server and do all kinds of magic.

You also need to add the `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices` and `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Auth` assemblies to your project

Use it like this

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
            // Setting credentials is unnecessary when you connect from a computer that is
            // logged on to the domain.
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(sUserName, sPassword, sDomain);
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
service.Url = new Uri(lsRootUri);
Folder inbox = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);        

inbox.Load();
ItemView iv = new ItemView(50);
FindItemsResults<Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item> emails = inbox.FindItems(iv);
foreach (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item email in emails)
{

}
```

Comment: Cool, I will have a play around with this later, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you really want to write it yourself, this product should do what you want:

http://www.email2db.com/

Not cheap but seems pretty full featured.